# Elasticsearch data size optimization

Tags: elasticsearch, optimization, schema

I was wondering, would it be good practice to optimize data like this in Elasticsearch?

Old data

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "firstname": "name",
    "lastname": "name",
    "email": "email"
}
```

New data

```
{
    "uid": 1,
    "f": "name",
    "l": "name",
    "e": "email"
}
```

Lets say, I have billions of documents with long named keys, would it save alot space if I used short named keys instead?

Or does elasticsearch compress data by default, so I don't need to worry about this?

I prefer to have data more readable, but if it could save a lot space, then its whole different thing.

This question is asked five years ago and it had only one answer, so would be nice to have more comments about this.

You can read it here:
[Elasticsearch scheme optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701041/elasticsearch-scheme-optimization)

Any thoughts from experienced elasticsearch developers?

Comment: Elasticsearch does use compression by default, see [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/does-elasticsearch-automatically-compress-data/93161/2). Lz4 is still [the default compression algorithm](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/index-modules.html#index-modules-settings).

Comment: Even thought it uses compression, should I minify data like on my example? How big difference it would make?

Comment: The compression algorithm should do exactly that. Try to gzip a bunch of json files and see the compression rate, I believe with/without "minify data" the difference will be minimal (== not worth doing minify).